# HttpWebOperation timing out. Why and what to check?

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest

I'm calling web service (my web service) like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(Options.ServerUri + Options.AccountId + "/integration/trip") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Timeout = 20000; // 20 seconds should be plenty, no need for 100 seconds
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Options.LoginName + ":" + Options.Password)));
request.Method = "POST";

var serializedData = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(trip);

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedData);

request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
var os = request.GetRequestStream();
os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
os.Close();

request.GetResponse();

LoggingAndNotifications.LogAndNotify(string.Format("Success uploading trip: {0}", trip.TripId), false);

return true;
```

This code called repeatedly to post new objects. After about 3 calls I start getting timeouts on `reguest.GetReponse()`

There is no errors on server side, nothing in Event Log. It feels like "something" stops me from repeatedly hitting service. What should I look for? Is it possible with company firewall? Or something wrong with my code?

Comment: So do those first 3 requests work, or are they queued up in the system somewhere?

Comment: Could it be that the responses are arriving out of order? For instance, your third request gets the response to the second request, the fourth get's the third's and so on.

Comment: This is syncronous code running on same thread. Just loop over objects and post one by one - this is exact code. There is no queue, server just stops responsing. I was wondering if there is something obvious wrong with code because I'm thinking it's server. But I would expect 500 or other server errors. Not timouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the response as per the example in the [doco](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28VS.71%29.aspx).

```
WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");

// Return the response. 
WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

// Code to use the WebResponse goes here.

// Close the response to free resources.
myResponse.Close();
```

Hmm. The doco also says

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

You should probably ask for a lock of some kind.

Comment: My problem went away but I mark is as an answer since it is definitely good idet to close response. Strange that code inspection didn't catch it

Comment: @katit Thanks for that. Did you work out why the problem went away?

Comment: No, because I didn't do anything for it to go away. It was looping - I was getting errors and than it started to work all of the sudden. Before that I emailed network admin, so maybe that had to do something :)

Comment: @katit Still, if it's locking up your thread, you should probably implement a timeout of some kind for whenever the problem raises its ugly head again.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you are not closing the response. Try editing your code as follows:

```
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is not caused by server side bugs?

It seems strange, as far as I known, the webrequest on .net4 is based on IOCP in lower layer, maybe you can try release web request/response resources after each loop.

Since the GetResponse() will return a stream, if you don't read from it, the real data may not transfer from server to client side. (I found this when I am trying to parse a response that I used peek(), and it always return an invalid value until the read() is called.)

So, try to read it or just close it.

Comment: I don't think it was a server. Looks like it was infrastructure (firewall problem) and it just disappeared